# As3 - Do I need to load a XML File in both scenes?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, xml-parsing, loader

I was just wondering, if i load my XML file in the scene 1, will i need to load it also in scene 2 too?

PS: Since i'm asking this, can somebody tell how to access a XML attribute?
Is it by just writing XMLname.Attributename?

Comment: Did you invest any time in reading [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html) ?

Comment: Yep, i just found about the attributes, but i was wondering for different scenes..

Answer (score 1):

What where you save it? If you save in lacal variable in frame, it will lost. That is because the life of this variable only exist on the same scene that the number frame is same or bigger that the storage. But if you save in a variable of document class, it will still available. It because the object is still available bound to document class of that object. I believe that XML Temporary data isn't stored at frames and gotoAndStop() function don't alter any object except applied, and variable in the frame of applied object.